# How to use noconflict jquery with qtip2

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I've an old Jquery(1.2.6) with my old Drupal installation.

I've added latest JQuery version(3.3.1) using [nonconflict](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) technique.

I want [jquery.qtip.min.js](https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/tree/master/dist) to use this latest version of Jquery.

I've tried to understand `jquery.qtip.js` code but unable to figure out the place it is getting initialized with JQuery.

What is the way to do it?

The order in which libraries are getting included:

1. JQuery 1.2.6
2. JQuery 3.3.1
3. QTip2

Comment: can you post your dependencies order here?

Comment: They have clearly mentioned in their document that qTip2 requires jQuery 1.6 and up, and is also compatible with the new jQuery 2.x releases.

Comment: How to use the QTip2 with JQuery 3.3.1 in my case?

Comment: As it does not support so you should use 2.x version. can I know what is special depencies on 3.3.1 in your project can I know.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this : https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/issues/695 and seems to be working

Comment: Can you include some of the relevant details?